# How to mock a property of a class in Laravel tests

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit, php-ziparchive

Im using the [ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class in my laravel 5.6 application for handling zip files. In my tests I have created a mock for the ZipArchive class as follows:

```
$this->zipArchiveMock = $this->createMock(ZipArchive::class);
```

Im able to mock methods on the ZipArchive class like follows:

```
$this->zipArchiveMock->expects($this->once())
            ->method('open')
            ->will($this->returnValue(true));
```

I want to mock a property called numFiles of the ZipArchive class. I tried doing `$this->zipArchiveMock->numFiles = 2`. But `$this->zipArchiveMock->numFiles` is always 0. How to mock a property on the ZipArchive class ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there are 2 options, you can either mock the public property with Mockery or mock the `count()` function.

```
$this->zipArchiveMock->set('numFiles', 2);
```

(I dont know if you use Mockery, but it is included in Laravel so i assumed you did)
http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/public_properties.html

Or:

```
$this->zipArchiveMock->expects($this->once())
    ->method('count')
    ->will($this->returnValue(2));
```

EDIT:

You are not using Mockery but PHPunit. I can't find a way to mock properties on an object or set properties on a mock with PHPUnit. Instead i suggest you use Mockery like this:

```
$this->zipArchiveMock = \Mockery::mock('ZipArchive');
$this->zipArchiveMock->set('numFiles', 2);

$this->zipArchiveMock->shouldReceive('open')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(true);
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Im using PHP 7.1.21 and the count() function for ZipArchive is only available in 7.2 (Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.count.php#123091) . So i have to use the numFiles property. I did `$this->zipArchiveMock->set('numFiles', 2);` as you suggested but then i get the error `Call to undefined method Mock_ZipArchive_90b9991f::set()` .

Comment: I just figured out you are using PHPUnit mocking. And i can't find a solution to your problem with PHPUnit. The `set()` method is a Mockery method. So i updated my question to explain Mockery some more.